# Access another array in handlebars #each iteration

Tags: handlebars.js

Say I have two arrays in my context file:

```
{
  "foo": [ ... ],
  "bar": [ ... ]
}
```

In my template, I want to do something like this:

```js
{{#each foo}}
  "{{ this }}": {{ bar.[{{@index}}] }}
{{/each}}
```

That is, I want to interpolate the values at the same index in `foo` and `bar`. However, the code doesn't work. The second value is empty in the output file (there's a "").

As per the documentation, I used [@index](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each) to reference the current loop index.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out - I have to use the [lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) built-in helper.

I had to change this line of the template from this:

```
"{{ this }}": {{ bar.[{{@index}}] }}
```

To this:

```
"{{ this }}": {{lookup ../values @index }}
```

More examples for how to use lookup can be found [here](https://zordius.github.io/HandlebarsCookbook/0020-lookup.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had to change this:

```
  <ol>
  {{#each oilMileage}}
      {{#each oilDate}}
  
      <li>{{../this}} miles, Date:{{this}}</li>
  
      {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
  </ol>
```

to this:

```
<ol>
 {{#each oilMileage}} 
   <li>
  

       {{this}} miles, {{lookup ../oilDate @index}}   
    

   </li>
 {{/each}}

  </ol>
```

because otherwise there would be two li's/line items because of the two {{each}}'s.

I also tried putting just one {{each}} and then referencing the second oilDate array but without the key the entire second array would print rather than just the iteration.   I think the correct solution as listed above is the use of lookup with @index, nothing else including using root.oilDate would work.